# Why is the Cloud Endpoints Contains Method Generated Like This?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When you generate a new cloud endpoint library the contains method always looks like this:

```
private boolean containsObject(Object object) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    boolean contains = true;
    try {
        mgr.getObjectById(Object.class, object.getId());
    } catch (javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException ex) {
        contains = false;
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return contains;
}
```

At first blush this looks like a good method, but considering the default insert method does a check with contains, the whole point of an insert is you don't have an id yet. So inserts always fail by default.

I get around this by putting a check for a null id in the contains method and then returning false if the id is null. But I assume I'm missing something, could someone please enlighten me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi - could you let us know what annotations you have on your entity class? In particular, the annotations at the class level, field level, and method level? Feel free to file an issue at https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/list and attach your entity class, if you prefer.

Comment: I just use the generate command through the Eclipse plugin, so you get something like this:

@Api(name = "endpointname", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "object.com", ownerName = "object.com", packagePath = "data"))

Comment: Actually, I'm not talking about the generated class. I'm talking about the class that was selected when you right-clicked and picked "Generate Cloud Endpoint". It should have an @Entity annotation at the class level..